# imagecopyresampled results to black square image, but imagescale is fine

Tags: php

I have a straightforward PHP script (php version 7+)  that I run to resize images to a smaller dimension around 1200px wide ...

I use imagecreatefromjpeg and imagecopyresampled method and the save new file with imagejpeg @ 88% compression.

I and ran over 100 images through it and most images worked out great, except for a few stubborn images that results to BLACK square image.

I tried imagecopyresized and played with different new dimensions but it just didnt work. I even tried outputting the ob stream from these tests at the point of resizing instead of saving to file (no compressions applied) and i can confirm that the moment the image was resized, it is already black square.

On the images that produces black square the result is false.

I did verify mime type IMAGETYPE_JPEG of file, regardless of file extension, before running the code.

Now, I tried running the same files thru imagescale instead
$new_img = imagescale($img, $new_width, $new_height, IMG_SINC );

and that worked.

Now I prefer to use the previous method for better more crispier output so I've been trying to get it to work :(

Why is this happening? I searched stack for similar issues but they are describing a issues that completely didnt work on any images, not my case, where only a select few images had issues.

I am dealing with JPG only, but is it possible that the jpg file is just named with extension ".jpg" but actually a png, bmp, or something else? Will that cause issues?

I'm stuck, and i hope you guys can help.

Thank you

Most images resized nicely

Comment: It's possible the images are not true JPGs, and/or are corrupt in some manner that prevents `imagecopyresized()` from working. You could try opening those files in Photoshop (or some similar editor) and resaving them.

Comment: I think the question cannot be answered without reproducible code including a JPG image which caused the error.